# RestKit 0.20: Multiple baseURLs / RKObjectManager

Tags: restkit-0.20

I have the requirement to support multiple connections (multiple baseURLs). So some get and post request should go to baseURL1 some to baseURL2 an so forth.

I think one way to do this is by constantly switching the baseURL to the needed one right before a get or post. I'm not sure how well RestKit 0.20 would handles this and if there are some side-effects. Generally I think it would be a bad idea with a lot of overhead. But I'm not a RestKit expert when it comes to the internal workings.

The other idea I have is to use multiple RKObjectManagers, one per baseURL and then somehow use the right one for the calls. But I have no idea if RestKit is designed for that and can be used in this scenario. How would you manage multiple RKObjectManagers? Or is this a bad idea to solve my problem?

What's the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `RKObjectManager`s. I would have a singleton data controller which abstracts the rest of the application away from the usage of RestKit and presents an interface in terms of your model objects. Internally it has a number of `RKObjectManager` instances and each method uses the appropriate one (they could be properties or you could have a dictionary of them depending on how you know when each should be used).

Comment: I agree, this would be a clean way to manage multiple `RKObjectManager`s. But what happens if you use multiple `RKObjectManager`s at the same time? Let's say you use one in the main thread and one in a `NSOperationQueue`. Do they interfere each other or is RestKit build, that this would be a safe operation?

Comment: Both should be used from the main thread. Model updates are processed on a background thread automatically and then merged into the main context. This is handled by RestKit.

Comment: Yes, shared manager is just the first created one (by default). Best raise a question with details of the exception and mappings / descriptors. @jafar